# StackOverflowException with Spark View Engine

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, spark-view-engine

Whenever I call Html.RenderAction from a Spark view I get a StackOverflowException. If the action returns ContentResult, everything works fine but when I change to ActionResult I bump into the exception.

I work with ASP.NET MVC 2 and latest Spark release (1.1.0.0)

Any ideas?

Comment: what does your view look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for completeness, you know this already, but the answer is on the Google group:

http://groups.google.co.uk/group/spark-dev/browse_thread/thread/cadd63c632a51a17/2c474ee3412f8375?lnk=gst&q=stackoverflow#2c474ee3412f8375